# difference between json created dynamically from response and one hardcoded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to set up a bootstrap typehead.Here is my jquery code

```
    $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://example.com/search?callback=my_callback",
        data: { keyword: 'r' },
        jsonpCallback: "my_callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
            var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
            alert("Excep:: " + exception + "Status:: " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });

    var sources = [
      { name: "local", type: "localStorage", key: "cities", display: "country" },
      { name: "remote", type: "remote", url: "/cities/list" },
      { name: "data", type: "data", data: [] }
    ];

    $('input.typeahead.local.remote').typeahead({
        sources: [
        { name: "local", type: "localStorage", key: "cities" }
      ]
    });
});

function my_callback(data) {
    alert(data.count);
    var src2 = '[';
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
        src2 = src2 + "{ id : " + (i + 1) + " , name: '" + data.response[i].name + "' },";

    }
    src2 = src2.substring(0, src2.length - 1);
    src2 = src2 + ']';
    var sampleJson = [{ id: 1, name: 'Really Awesome' }, { id: 2, name: 'RSpecge'}];
    localStorage.setItem("cities", JSON.stringify(src2));
}
```

In my callback function when i set `localStorage` using the data returned from jquery ajax call it doesn't work.But when i try to set the data directly using variable `sampleJson`  it works.
Y is it so??

Here is the json dynamically created from response from jquery ajax which looks the same as the sampleJson

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'Really Awesome' }, { id: 2, name: 'RSpecge'}]
```

And here is sampleJson

```
var sampleJson = [{ id: 1, name: 'Really Awesome' }, { id: 2, name: 'RSpecge'}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify "doesn't work"? Trying to serialize your data to a JSON string by hand is unnecessary and error prone. Manipulate your data as regular javascript objects then use `JSON.stringify` to convert it to a string when ready. It will produce actual JSON, which, for example, requires all keys to be enclosed within double quotes, whereas your code is generating javascript object literal syntax that permits most keys to be unquoted.